# Tag property of a ListViewItem references duplicate of object rather than original one

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a `FooCollection(of FooObject)`.
I populate a ListView with ListViewItems:

```
Sub PopulateListView()
    For Each MyFoo as FooObject in FooCollection
        Dim MyItem as New ListViewItem(MyFoo.Name)
        MyItem.Tag=MyFoo
        ListView1.Items.Add(MyItem)
    Next
End Sub
```

I have an event where I want to modify the property of the Active Item in the list:

```
Sub MyEvent() Handles ListView1.DoubleClick
    Dim ActiveFoo as FooObject = ListView1.FocusedItem.Tag
    ActiveFoo.Name = "SomethingNew"
End Sub
```

If I then call `PopulateListView()`, the content of the ListView does not change (`ListViewItem.text` is still the same).

The scenario is actually more complex than that: it includes serialization and the collection is actually a `BindingList` which handles ListChanged and Serializes/Deserializes each time the collection is accessed.
I suspect the problem is over there, but before going into a headache and refactoring I would like to make sure I am not missing something more basic.

C# answers are ok.

---

As requested in comments, additional info here:

```
Public Class FooObject
    Property Name as String
End Class


Public Class MyModel

    Property FooCollection As ICollection(Of FooObject)
        Get
            Dim SerializedObject as String = GetStringFromFile() 
            If SerializedObject = vbNullString Then
                _FooCollection = New BindingList(Of FooObject)
                _FooCollection.RaiseListChangedEvents = True
            Else
                Dim MyJSON As String = GetStringFromFile()
                _FooCollection= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of BindingList(Of FooObject))(MyJSON)
            End If
            Return _FooCollection
        End Get
        Set(value As ICollection(Of FooObject))
            SetStringToFile(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value))
        End Set
    End Property

    Private WithEvents _FooCollection As BindingList(Of FooObject)

    Private Sub _PopulatedExhibits_ListChanged(sender As Object, e As ListChangedEventArgs) Handles _FooCollection.ListChanged
        Dim MyBindingList As BindingList(Of FooObject) = sender
        SetStringToFile(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MyBindingList))
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Maybe FooObject is a struct. Maybe you're deserializing it multiple times, creating a new instance each time. If you post a more complete example, that would help.

Comment: Hi Ed, I just added som extra info.

Comment: Right, you set a property on an item from FooCollection that's the tag of a listviewitem, then you replace all the items in FooColleciton with new items, and you replace all the list view items with new list view items whose tags reference new FooObjects from the new FooCollection. This is one reason why the getter you wrote for FooCollection is an anti-pattern. Is there any reason to repopulate every time you enumerate the collection? Anyhow: In PopulateListView(), before you break everything, save the info you need to restore the listview state. Restore it at the end of PopulateListView().

Comment: `GetStringFromFile()` retrieves a value from a Word document Variable. Each time an action is made on the FooCollection I need to store the new state into this Doc Variable so that the state is saved if the user saves the file. My FooObjects have a `.UniqueId` property. Now I am thinking of tagging that property instead of the FooObject itself.

Comment: I did not understand your point regarding `PopulateListView()`

Comment: What don't you understand? You have some kind of state that's getting stepped on there. Something you changed in one of the FooObjects. That change exists at the start of the method. Then you replace all the FooObjects with new ones, and the successor to the changed one doesn't have the change. Save the change in a variable at the start of PopulateListView(), and re-apply it at the end.

Comment: Ok maybe I wasn't 100% clear. What I really need is not the ListView to display the change (I do but that is not the main goal). What I want is the Collection to account for the change I make to one of its items, and then the ListView is just a representation of that Collection.

Comment: So you're saying that every time you change the collection, you throw away the changes you just made, and replace the collection with the previous version, but you regret doing that? At least I think that's what's happening.

Comment: Every time the collection is changed, a serialized version of the change is stored. Every time the collection is read, a new instance of the collection is created from deserialization.  It worked fine until now as all I was doing was adding/removing items in the collection. But now I am storing a reference to a given item of that collection, which is not serialized because `.ListChanged` does not trigger.

Comment: As I wrote above, I think if I (1) Pull the current state of the Collection, (2) run a `.FindIndex(function(p) p.UniqueId = FooObject.UniqueId)`, and (3) Push the new state of the Collection, that should work. But as you said, the behaviour is anti-pattern..

Comment: CollectionChanged is raised when you add an item to the collection, delete an item, or replace an item with a different one. That's all. It doesn't monitor the items in the collection for changes to their properties. That should be pretty clear from the documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the reference to the object which is lost if another call was made to the FooCollection before triggering `MyEvent`.

Individual objects of the collection can be replaced like this. This is however far from being optimal, so any improvements are welcome !

```
Partial Class MyModel

    Sub ReplaceObject(NewObjects As IEnumerable(Of FooObject))

        Dim TempCollection As New List(Of FooObject)(Me.FooCollection.ToList)

        For Each NewObject As FooObject In NewObjects 
            Dim ExistingObjectIndex As Integer = TempCollection.FindIndex(Function(p) p.UniqueId = NewObject.UniqueId)
            TempCollection.Item(ExistingObjectIndex) = NewObject 
        Next

        Me.FooCollection = TempCollection

    End Sub

End Class
```